# Keep socket connection open in webview on Android

Tags: android, webview, socket.io, disconnect, android-doze-and-standby

I have a web app that is now being used in an Android app by launching it in a webview. Most of the Android functionality is native & the webview part is mainly just for communication via socket.io

It all works okay but as soon as the phone goes to sleep it kills the socket connection after a few minutes. This connection is used for incoming messaging so I need the connection to stay alive.

I tried creating a foreground service and using it as a keep-alive but since the socket connection is in the webview, it still gets closed no matter what I do i.e. the service stays alive and I can make a new network connection, but I can't keep the existing app connection alive.

Is there a way to keep a webview socket connection alive when the phone dozes? Am I doing something wrong? Or is my design flawed and I need a different approach?

Comment: Have you tried [using the Java Socket.IO library](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) instead of the `WebView`?

Comment: @CommonsWare I haven't tried that. We just migrated the project as it was, and as such used a webview. I'll try that out. Thanks.